# Retrieve images asynchronously using UISlider in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, asynchronous, nstimer, nsthread

How do I retrieve images asynchronously and put it on UIImageView  in iPhone programming ? Till now I was doing it synchronously, but the delay in retrieving the images is more, hence I would like to take the faster approach.

I used NSTimer & NSThread , but the control is not entering into them.. No idea why its happening so..

Can you please help me out?

Thank you in advance.
Suse

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4331974/how-to-improve-performance-while-using-uiwebview-in-cells-of-table-view/4332608#4332608) which suggests using EGOImageView which loads images asynchronously. I also use this class and it works great for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using AFNetworking also. Works great!
In fact there's a lot of lib offering asynchronous image download.